How can copper function as a Faraday Cage and Antenna?
How can copper serve both purposes of capturing waves as an antenna and also block waves when used as a faraday cage for EMI shielding? How can the same material do both: capture and block?

If I capture you, can you get away? Or have I blocked you? A Faraday cage does not mean it blocks RF. Any frequency smaller than the spacing or holes passes right through.

A wire can short a signal out or conduct it to another place.

When an electromagnetic field reaches a conductive surface, it causes the charges (electrons) in that surface to move — generally in a direction parallel to the E-field and perpendicular to the B-field.
This movement can have several effects, depending on the shape of the conductor.
A long thin wire oriented in the same direction as the E-field can multiply the effects of this movement and produce voltage at its ends and current in its middle.
This is the basis for the dipole antenna — we cut the wire in the middle and measure the current with a low-impedance load.
But if the conductor is a large flat surface, this movement of charges produces a counter-field that effectively reflects the electromagnetic energy away, like a mirror. The original field does not penetrate the surface, and if the surface happens to be a closed box, none of the energy gets inside — this is called a Faraday cage.
So, bottom line, it's the same property of the conductor that gives rise to both uses.

ok thank you, just for me to understand what does large mean? Is there a threshold in size when it switches from an antenna to a mirror? And the charge produced in the large surface due to  the EM energy can be grounded so as to not produce voltage and current like it would if it was a long thin wire?

It doesn't switch based on size. It switches based on shape and how it's connected to other circuitry.

And grounding doesn't prevent the production of current -- it just directs the current in a particular way.
